# why this C++ program runs so strange,the program died when added a empty function

Tags: c++

my code are as follows ,path1.updatePathInfo() is an function which  call an empty function,if delete this  it will works fine.I could't understand.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include "CPath.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    for(int i = 0;i<10;++i)
    {
        cout<<i;
        CPath path1;
        CPath path2;
        cross(path1,path2);
        path1.updatePathInfo();  //this is an function which call an empty function
                                 //if I delete this it works fine.I could't understand.
        path2.updatePathInfo();

    }
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////CPath.h

```
#ifndef CPATH_H_
#define CPATH_H_
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>
#include<map>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdlib>
class CPath
{
public:
    CPath();
    friend void cross(CPath & path1,CPath & path2);
    void updatePathInfo();
    std::vector< int > getPathByCode();
    void createRadomCode();
    std::vector< int > code;
    double pathLineLength;
};
#endif //CPATH_H_
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////CPath.cpp

```
#include"CPath.h"
CPath::CPath()
{
    createRadomCode();
}

void cross(CPath & path1,CPath & path2)
{
    int max,min;
    max = rand()%8;
    min = rand()%8;
    if(min > max)
    {
        max ^= min;min ^= max;max ^= min;
    }
    if(0.9*100>rand()%100)
    {
        for(int i = min;i<=max;++i)
        {
            path1.code[i]^=path2.code[i];
            path2.code[i]^=path1.code[i];
            path1.code[i]^=path2.code[i];
        }
    }
}

void CPath::updatePathInfo()
{
    getPathByCode();
}

std::vector< int > CPath::getPathByCode()
{
    //this function has nothing 
}

void CPath::createRadomCode()
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i<8 ; ++i)
    {
        code.push_back(rand()%(i+1));
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Comment: `CPath::getPathByCode()` is supposed to return a vector.  You have nothing inside there.  Is that **really** your code?  Please don't post code that isn't what you're actually using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CPath::getPathByCode()` does not return a value and the result is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  Your compiler is not required to tell you about this, but if you compile with all warnings enabled it almost certainly will.

As an aside, if you formatted your code correctly, this sort of error would be much easier to see.

Comment: Compilers are not required by the standard to detect missing return values. Some report errors, some give a warning, some remain silent.

Comment: @Fred, you're right, looks like I've been spoiled by the Visual C++ compiler. g++ indeed compiles this and the result is undefined behavior.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: that's what you get if you don't turn `-Werror=return-type` on. The warnings, and this one in particular, should be enabled and treated as errors.

Comment: I've edited the answer to reflect the undefined behaviour you've pointed out.